# Camera mount compatible with different straps

Tags: camera-straps

I have a rather heavy Nikon d850, and I'm trying to find better ways of carrying it around. I'm also sharing it with my girlfriend on trips (shooting with two cameras and switching around), and it seems that we have different strap preferences: I seem to prefer a shoulder strap, while she seems more into belt straps.

In a perfect world, there would be a mounting system with a quick release mechanism that could be used for different straps. But we don't live in a perfect world - I couldn't find any manufacturer that provides a unified quick release mount system for multiple strap types. The closest I've come across is a [belt strap](https://spiderholster.com/products/spiderpro-dslr-single-camera-system-v2) and a [shoulder strap](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/32854642936.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2deu) which use a ball mechanism for quick release.

So, do you happen to know of a quick release system that can be used for multiple types of straps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One company that has been around for a long time and specialises in camera straps is OP/TECH USA. I'm not affiliated with them, but I have been a satisfied customer of theirs for multiple products. They have many different styles, and most can be swapped around to your taste using side-release buckles. They haven't really updated any of their designs in years, so they are not a "cool" new company, but their hardware works.

Product recommendations are off-topic here, because the answers outlive the specific products mentioned, and because what's right for one person is not the right answer for others. Anyway, I guess the take-away is that you just need to look further. There are manufacturers that offer quick release solutions, with some attaching to the tripod socket (e.g. BLACKRAPID) or a tripod plate, and others to the regular strap lugs (e.g. Peak Design). You might be able to rig something together from multiple manufacturers which allows both of you to have different quick-release strap attachments on the camera at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Carry Speed F2 folding plate (apparently cross branded as Focus) with the spider holster system. The F2 pin is cross compatible, but the spider pin is (was?) slightly too large for the strap connection.

Comment: To whoever downvoted; please consider adding a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Peak Design. They have a quick-release spring-loaded fitting, which is compatible with all of their straps. I have a cuff (wrist) and a leash (neck). They also provide an anchor mount, which attaches to the tripod mount. IIRC I got an anchor mount bundled with my cuff.

I don't have any experience of using them, but they also provide anchor links which can be mated with your existing strap(s).

Comment: To whoever downvoted; please consider adding a reason.

Comment: All answers received 1 downvote, including mine. I can only assume it was done out of principle at answering a question in the usually-off-topic area of product recommendation

Comment: Then they should flag the question as opinion-based, and put it up for review.